# Synchronize timestamps on directories

Tags: bash

Let's say I have two directories with the same structure and I want to set the timestamps of files, contained in the second to those of the first if and only if  the content of the files is the same.

I give an answer here but if you guys have less clumsy and more efficient ways of achieving the goal, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

An even easier way is simply:

```
rsync -uav /path/to/dir1/ /path/to/dir2
```

(removing `v` suppresses `--verbose` output)

***note:*** the trailing `'/'` following `dir1`. It tells `rsync` to take the *contents* of `dir1` instead of `dir1` itself.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDDIR=$(readlink -f $1)
NEWDIR=$(readlink -f $2)

cd $NEWDIR
for file in $(find .); do
    file2=$OLDDIR/$file
    if test -e "$file2" && diff >/dev/null -q "$file" "$file2" ; then
        touch -r "$file2" "$file"
    fi
done
```